What are common encryption algorithm in NodeJS and Postgres which will give same output?
I have to encrypt text in NodeJs and decrypt in Postgres query.
So need an algorithm that gives the same output in Nodejs and Postgres.
I have tried many solutions but no one worked. Any help save my lots of time. Thanks in advance

Postgres is a database query language, are you sure you want to decrypt things in postgres? Surely the application running the postgres queries would be the one you want doing the encryption/decryption?

You can encrypt the plaintext with openpgp:
const encrypted = await openpgp.encrypt({
        message: await openpgp.createMessage({ text: 'Hello, World!' }), // input as Message object
        encryptionKeys: publicKey,
        signingKeys: privateKey // optional
    });

Then use pgp_sym_decrypt() from pgcrypto extension in PostgreSQL to decrypt it:
select pgp_sym_decrypt( the_encrypted_message_from_node
                       ,the_private_key_matching_the_public_key
                       ,'compress-algo=0, cipher-algo=aes256');

You need a matching pair of private and public keys, and make sure the compression algorithm, encryption method and encoding of the message all match.

How does that help Node.js?

@duffymo Are you saying it won't work in Node.js? I'm not sure what you're trying to ask or suggest.

How do you call that method in Node.js?

The first link above leads to a manual showing how to set that up in node, step-by-step - the example in the answer only shows how you end up actually encrypting the message and is a direct quote from that manual. The second example is a plain SQL query you can run from whatever client or library you prefer, and the link above it leads to the documentation of the extension, also providing more details.
